# Unity Mirror Commands problem. (damaging)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, mirror

When host calls the command, that's okay, another client damage been taked. But when client calls the command, nothing happens.

```
public class GunScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    void Shoot()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer) { return; }
        cam = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        recoilScript = cam.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Recoil>();
        Debug.Log("shoot");
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range, ignore))
        {
            hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Target>()?.TakeDamage(25f - hit.distance * 0.1f);
        }
        recoilScript.RecoilFire();
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdShoot()
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}
```

```
public class Target : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    [SyncVar] public int health;

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        health -= (int)damage;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }
}
```

The problem is that only host can call the command. Can the command be called by the client? Maybe there's another way to do it?

Comment: a) the check `if (!isLocalPlayer) { return; }` should not happen there but wherever `CmdShoot` is called from. b) `GameObject.Find("MainCamera")` you probably do **NOT** want to raycast always from the host's camera but rather from the local client's -> make the raycast local and rather send a command to the target you want to damage ...